# Time Limit Error when not passing a vector as reference in a recursion function

Tags: performance, data-structures, graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I was Solving a [GeeksForGeeks question](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-cycle-in-a-graph/) ,in which we had to find if a given directed graph is cyclic or not. I was using a visited array and a path visited array to see the visited nodes only in a given path. If we encounter a path visited node when traversing the path we say the directed graph is cyclic.

In this code sample using dfs, I passed visited and path visited arrays by reference and updated the path visited array to 0, when backtracking the path.

```
bool dfs(int i ,vector<int> adj[] , vector<int> &vis,vector<int> &pvis, int V)
{
    vis[i]=1;
    pvis[i]=1;
    bool temp;
   for(int j = 0 ; j< adj[i].size() ; j++)
   {    
       
       if(vis[adj[i][j]]==0)
       {
          
           
           if(dfs(adj[i][j], adj, vis, pvis,V)== true)
           {
               return true;
           }
       }
       else if(pvis[adj[i][j]]==1)
       {
            return true;
       }
   }
   pvis[i] = 0;
   return false;
}



bool isCyclic(int V, vector<int> adj[]) {
    vector<int> vis(V,0);
    vector<int> pvis(V,0);
    // int vis[V] = {0};
    // int pvis[V] = {0};
    for(int i = 0; i< V ;i++)
    
    {
        if(vis[i]==0)
        {
            if(dfs(i,adj,vis,pvis,V)==true)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

This was running properly without any time limit error.

But when I passed only the visited array as reference , and path visited array without reference, there was no need to update the path visited array, as it is local to each call.
When I used this approach I got time limit error

```
    bool dfs(int i ,vector<int> adj[] , vector<int> &vis,vector<int> pvis, int V)
{
    vis[i]=1;
    pvis[i]=1;
    bool temp;
   for(int j = 0 ; j< adj[i].size() ; j++)
   {    
       
       if(vis[adj[i][j]]==0)
       {
          
           
           if(dfs(adj[i][j], adj, vis, pvis,V)== true)
           {
               return true;
           }
       }
       else if(pvis[adj[i][j]]==1)
       {
            return true;
       }
   }
   
   return false;
}



bool isCyclic(int V, vector<int> adj[]) {
    vector<int> vis(V,0);
    vector<int> pvis(V,0);
    // int vis[V] = {0};
    // int pvis[V] = {0};
    for(int i = 0; i< V ;i++)
    
    {
        if(vis[i]==0)
        {
            if(dfs(i,adj,vis,pvis,V)==true)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return false;
}
```

Why is there a difference, both should give the same answer when given a testcase? Why is there a runtime difference?

Comment: " both should mean the same"  Most certainly not!  Please read up on the differences between passing by reference and passing by value.

Comment: @ravenspoint I know the difference between passing by value and passing by reference, that is the reason I am updating the vector while backtracking when passed by reference and not while passing by value. If there's something I am missing please point it out

Comment: If you know the difference, why did you write " both should mean the same"?

Comment: I meant both the codes should return the same answer when given a testcase, I wanted to know why there's a time limit exception on one and not on the other

Comment: Edit your question so that it does not suggest you are ignorant of the difference.